# MVC - Paged List: keeping all my values in memory with textbox, checkbox and dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am building an MVC app that will display a bit of data at screen. I might end up having hundreds or maybe even thousands of data.

So I'm using a PagedList format following this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Which helped me. The Paged List works. But I have one problem that I can't seem to figure out how to solve. In the tutorial, there's only 1 parameter, a textbox, and the tutorial keeps the value "in memory" by keeping and attributing the ViewBag parameter so that changing page does not "flush" the text in the textbox.

Right now I'm building something like a search engine with, right now, 23 parameters and counting. Amongst these parameters are checkboxes, textboxes, and dropdownlists.

My question: is there any way to keep these in memory? How may I proceed? Must I keep them all in memory just like the tutorial does?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the tutorial, they are not really "kept in memory" between requests. In each request, the value is passed into the action method, which then passes it to the view where it is used in creating the paging and sorting links.

Previously, when paging, instead of adding each parameter individually, I simply have a method that reads the querystring and builds the link using each provided parameter:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

foreach (string key in queryString)
{
   if (key != null)
   {
       if (!newValues.ContainsKey(key))
       {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString[key]))
           {
                newValues[key] = queryString[key];
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Then, to create the link, I use:

```
            string link;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(routeName))
            {
                link = helper.RouteLink(text, routeName, newValues).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                actionName = actionName ?? values["action"].ToString();
                controllerName = controllerName ?? values["controller"].ToString();

                link = helper.ActionLink(text, actionName, controllerName, newValues, null).ToString();
            }

            return string.Concat(" ", link);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX techniques, then you can create 2 action methods in your controller.

The first should return the whole view and the second should return a partial view.

The first will contain your search controls (all 23 of them). These will be rendered only the first time.

The second one will return the partial view and will be parameterized by the 23 odd parameters you have to your search query. It might be an idea to stuff them all in a ViewModel class and let the default model binder bind it at run time.

Finally, you can then load the results part of the search results page by an AJAX call to the 2nd method using JavaScript/jQuery.